# Which set had these LEGO cars with Pat. Pend.?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, vintage

I have three of these they are marked Pat. Pend. all pieces are the body's are white blocks wheels are red.
What set are these from? [image]

Answer (score 13):

These are [Train Base 4 x 7 with Wheels Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=824&name=Train%20Base%204%20x%207%20with%20Wheels%20Holder&category=%5BTrain%5D#T=C&C=1)

[image]
with [Train Wheel with 2 x 2 Stud Center, Traction Teeth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=wheel1a&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

[image]

and [Turntable 4 x 4 Complete, Perfectly Round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3404bc01&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

[image]

They were found in [two](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=153-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) [sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=113-2#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 1966:
[image]
[image]